# Install charm crypto on windows 10

Tags: charm-crypto, charm

PLEASE i can't isntall charm chrypto on windows10 , can anyone guide me? and send me all the dependecies to install with links , cuz i don't find them pleaaasee
to help me find dependecies and install charm crypto, pleaase

Answer (score 0):

Charm crypto-library is just too difficult to install in Windows. The best option is to use Docker and follow the Docker instructions in the Charm documentation. With that process, you will get an Ubuntu container with Charm included. Run the container in the attached interactive mode so you can use it from Windows with, for instance, VS Code remote explorer. That is the way I'm currently using Charm for my projects.